# PS Script to open multiple powershell sessions

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to call a powershell script in multiple windows at once to install software.  This will solve the issue having to remote into each server and calling this script from our central server.  I need the script to launch multiple windows in order to interact with the install script's custom powershell menus. Thanks in advance.

```
Clear-Host

#Get-Credential

$a = @()

do{
 $input = (Read-Host "Please enter the computer name")
 if ($input -ne '') {$a += $input}
 cls
 Write-Host "Current servers: $($a)"
}until ($input -eq '')

$session
cls
for($i=0;$i -lt $a.Length;$i++)
{

    if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $a[$i] -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ErrorAction 0 -Quiet))
    {    
        Write-Host $a[$i] -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Red
    }
    else
    {
        $session = New-PSSession $a[$i]
        #$compString = ($computerarray|group|?{$_.count}|Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ", "

        #Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {Start-Process powershell '\\SERVER\D$\Inetsvcs\Software\IIS\test.ps1'}

        #Invoke-expression 'cmd /c start powershell -Command {"\\SERVER\D$\Inetsvcs\Software\IIS\test.ps1"}'

        Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath "\\SERVER\D$\Inetsvcs\Software\IIS\test.ps1"
    }
}


foreach ($server in $a) {Remove-PSSession -ComputerName $server}
```

Comment: Have you considered just rewriting the install script to not require interaction?

Comment: The easiest way would be to have another file that just split these loops into two files and in the first loop call the other. However, as Mathias said, making this script not require interaction is a much better approach, i.e. passing it a list of computer names in a text file.

Comment: Before you go through this trouble, have you tested this remote installation to make sure that you aren't going to run into double hop issues? Working on ServerA, creating a remote session on ServerB, from which you try to access resources on ServerC usually is a whole other can of worms to worry about, and that's what it looks like you're doing.